# Convert ISO Date to Date Format to LONG Date format in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i get date having format Dec 27 2017 from iso date?

MY ISO date is

> 2017-12-27 00:00:00

How can i get this

> Dec 27 2017

Comment: sorry i this is August 27 2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Note: The question I am flagging as duplicate is not an exact duplicate, but it does show everything you need to get to your answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString `var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
new Date('2017-12-27 00:00:00Z').toLocaleDateString('en-US',options);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do this.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
    "Nov", "Dec"
  ];

  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' +day + ' ' + year;
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date())); // show current date-time in console
```

Ref: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/5894241)

Comment: Instead of posting an answer to the duplicate question (which you've linked twice now), cast a close vote or flag it as a duplicate. Posting another answer isn't beneficial to the site, when there's a perfectly suitable existing answer.